# react input component gets store overwritten onChange

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Ok, I'm new to react and mobx, and I'm experiencing some issues to manipulate the store.

When I'm typing at the input, the value gets overwritten for each char typed.

The component:

```
@withStore
@observer
class ConfigModel extends Component {
    configModel;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.configModel = this.props.store.configModelStore;
    }

    render() {
        const fieldsObj = this.configModel.modelConfig;
        const fieldHelpers = this.configModel.helperModelStore.modelConfig;
        const callbackOnChange = this.configModel;

        const campos = merge(fieldHelpers, fieldsObj); // _.merge()

        return (
            <Form key={'configModelForm'}>
                <>
                    {Object.entries(campos).map((campo) => {
                        if (campo[1].advanced) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (campo[1].type === 'input') {
                            return (
                                <InputRender
                                    key={campo[1].id}
                                    field={campo[1]}
                                    onChange={callbackOnChange.valueOnChange}
                                />
                            );
                        }
                    })}
                </>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

And my store define some observables (some options were omitted for simplicity, like the `type` evaluated at the component above):

```
  @observable modelConfig = [{
      id: 'postType',
      value: '',
      disabled: false,
      advanced: false,
    },
    {
      id: 'pluralName',
      value: '',
      disabled: false,
      advanced: true,
    },
    ...
  ]
```

And also define some actions:

```
  @action valueOnChange = (e, {id, value}) => {
    this.modelConfig.filter((config, index) => {
      if (config.id === id) {
        this.modelConfig[index].value = value;
        console.log(this.modelConfig[index].value);
      }
    });
```

The `console.log()` above prints:

[image: the values gets overwritten for each char typed]

I truly believe that I'm forgetting some basic concept there, so can someone spot what am I doing wrong?

---

*EDIT:

I have another component and another store that is working correctly:

```
@observable name = '';
  @action setName = (e) => {
    this.name = e.target.value;
    console.log(this.name);
  }
```

So my question is:

**Why the action that targets a specific value like `this.name` works fine and the action that targets a index generated value like `this.modelConfig[index].value` doesn't works?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at the `<InputRender>` component that was also receiving the `@observable` decorator. Just removed and it worked.

```
// @observer <---- REMOVED THIS
class InputRender extends Component {
    render() {
        const item = this.props.field;
        return (
            <InputField
                id={item.id}
                label={
                    <InfoLabel
                        label={item.label}
                        action={item.action}
                        content={item.popupContent}
                    />
                }
                placeholder={item.placeholder}
                onChange={this.props.onChange}
                value={item.value}
                disabled={item.disabled}
                error={item.error}
                throwError={item.throwError}
            />
        );
    }
}
```